# what is the equivalent of boolean? in Clojure

Tags: types, clojure, boolean

Scheme supports `boolean?` to test whether a symbol or value is of boolean type.

```
(boolean? #\t)
(boolean? #\f)
```

While in Clojure, I can only found `integer?`, `number?`, `list?`, etc but without `boolean?`.

What is the equivalent of `boolean?` in Clojure?

Comment: Keep in mind that `true` is not the only true value, and `false`is not the only false value.  You probably know that.  This is just a warning to newbies reading this later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could do

```
(defn boolean? [x]
  (instance? Boolean x))
```

Answer (score 8):

Yet another version:

```
(defn boolean? [x]
  (or (true? x) (false? x)))
```

Comment: Is there a value of x that can make this function return false? I would think no matter what you give it, it will return true. false is falsey, null is falsey and everything else you could give it is truthy.

Comment: Every value except for Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE make this function return false. Read the docs of true? and false?. They're exactly for distinguishing truthiness from real boolean values.

Comment: That's great, and works for Clojurescript too (I just tested in cljs and clj REPLs).

Answer (score 4):

- In Clojure, all values are logical: valid first arguments to an [`if`
  form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(if%20test%20then%20else?)) and all its progeny. In that sense, everything is boolean.
- The only false values are `nil` and `false` itself. Though
  `Boolean/FALSE`, a static object containing `false`, and `(Boolean.
  false)` - a new `Boolean` object containing `false` - evaluate
  false. This last does not accord with how I read the documentation, but that's
  what Light Table is showing me. I'd say steer clear of constructing your
  own `Boolean`s. Why Java allows it, I can't fathom.
- I've never come across a case where the logic required knowing
  whether something was  in the set `#{true false}`. If you need to do so,
  follow [Shlomi's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29587909/1562315).
- Many standard functions produce `nil` for *nothing* or *failure*. For
  example, a set applied to a non-member. In such cases, you may find
  yourself using `nil?` to test for `nil`, particularly where `false`
  would be a valid and distinct value.

Comment: While in general the need for this doesn't seem valid, one case where one would want to do this is if a command-line option such as a debug flag was to be input to the program.  In such a case the coder would want to ensure that the user clearly set a true value and did not provide some non-false value by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Since [Clojure 1.9](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/UEtE1K9C7XE/5p5BJe2tAQAJ) there is a [`boolean?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/boolean_q) predicate function in `clojure.core`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the land of types, and want to know if something is a boolean, then as Shlomi has posted you can make a `boolean?` function easily enough from `instance?`. Here's a varargs version:

```
(defn bools? 
  [& xs]
  (every? (partial instance? Boolean) xs))
```

with outputs:

```
>> (bools? true) => true
>> (bools? true false) => true
>> (bools? true nil) => false
```

I've never needed to do this, as I've only ever dealt with values and the fact that everything in clojure is "truthy" except for false or nil.

Answer (score 1):

`(defn bool? [x] (= x (boolean x)))`